# Identifying this component adapter/socket

Tags: identification, components, adapter, socket, plastic

I'm sorting an old collection of electronic components, some of which I don't know what they are used for, like this one:

[image: top]
[image: side]
[image: upside down]

This component is about 7 mm wide. Does anyone recognize this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: with scale

[image]

Comment: do a photo of the top and include a mm scale level with the top.

Comment: Looks like one of these coming up googling "4 pin circular connector".

Comment: @Jasen good point, I have added a new photo.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I could not find a relevant photo when Googling that search term. Maybe it's a regional issue. Can you provide more information on what you have found?

Comment: I don't have the exact one, but I see some very similar ones. Maybe you can take a closer look at these and see if the pin spacing is the same. Not sure why would you need this info, by the way. Looks like just some connector you can use for different applications...

Comment: maybe a 4 pin vacuum tube base?

Comment: @jsolarski Good guess. The extra 4 "bumps" seem typical for these

Comment: After Googling a little further with the search terms you suggested, I found a very similar match for TO18008D or TO5 transistors. More similar items can be found by googling "transistor socket 4 pin". Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a type of 4-pin transistor mount. Similar results can be found by Googling "TO-5 transistor socket".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a 4 pin ZIF carrier.

The arms probably flip up, which allows a fragile or flimsy component lead to be inserted.

Then the arms would flip down and the assembly would plug into another connector.

It may be used for transistors, or possibly for sensor wires.

or

It could be the core from a connector.

It clips onto the end of a 4 wire cable, as described above, but the rest of the connector is missing.